# Why is the paragraph margins overlapping and being ignored?

Tags: html, css

I have two pages, with the same layout and the same CSS stylesheets, on one page it, works fine, on the other, the margins for the paragraph seem to overlap and be ignored completely

I am unable to post all of the source code due to the amount, I would just like to know what could cause this to happen.

[image: Margins not working on paragraph tag]

Comment: What paragraphs? What margins? That screenshot shows list items and no CSS margin properties.

Comment: @Quentin The screenshot shows that the margins are overlapping, my question was what could cause this to happen. I'm not trying to get someone to review my code for me to fix it. I just want to understand why this happens. Thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Margins collapse.

If you have two elements each with `margin: 10px`, then you get `10px` of space between them, which is counterintuitive if you expected `10+10 = 20px` of space.

In this case, the margins collapse, but also you seem to have an issue with heights as the `<p>` itself does not fully contain its text. But notice how the margin stops at the exact place on the next line, as where the top of the content box is? This is how you can see that the margin has collapsed.

This is by design. If you want to avoid collapsing, try using `padding` instead, and no margin. Padding does not collapse like margin does.

Comment: From what you said, I noticed that the "ul li" items didn't have any height. I have manually given them a height and its displaying correctly. However I am unsure why they don't have height as other pages do. Thanks

Comment: If you have maybe a `float` for your content, then it does not give height to its container.

Comment: I checked for that aswell. All pages use the same CSS, and nothing is additional.